# Zend Server 6.3 MySql error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-server

I am new to zend Server. I installed it and now was trying to deploy phpmyadmin. but i get this error

```
error:
post_stage.php error: 
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the            future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\zend\ZendServer\tmp\zdd\.fv1464\post_stage.php on line 61

Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the target machine 
actively     refused it.
in C:\zend\ZendServer\tmp\zdd\.fv1464\post_stage.php on line 61

Could not connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively 
refused it.
```

Please Help...

Comment: As said in the error message, your mysql server is up ?

Comment: Have you tried to login to your MySQL server via the command line?...